# First item visible on a dropdown click menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have adapted this menu I found on Codepen to a section of my website.

I would like to get the first menu item visible when loading the page but hidden when clicking on the other menu items.

How can I do that?

### ----------------------

### ----------------------

### ----------------------

### ----------------------

### ----------------------

---

```js
$(document).on('click', '.itemscabecera', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.itemscabecera').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('.itemscabecera').removeClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', '.mega-menu', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); 
})
```

```css
.itemscabecera {width: 12%;
margin:0.15rem; 
-webkit-border-radius: 6;
-moz-border-radius: 6;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px 3px 20px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align:center;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
font-family: Arial;
cursor: pointer;
}


.mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  display: none;
  width: 140px;
  bottom: -92px;
  left: -1px;
}


.itemscabecera.active .mega-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>1st menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>2nd menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>3rd menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>4th menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>5th menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
  
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just insert `active` class to first `div.itemscabecera` like this:

```
<div class="itemscabecera active">
```

And **remove** this function:

```
$(document).on('click', function() {
  $('.itemscabecera').removeClass('active');
});
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.itemscabecera', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.itemscabecera').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', '.mega-menu', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); 
})
```

```css
  .itemscabecera {width: 12%;
margin:0.15rem; 
-webkit-border-radius: 6;
-moz-border-radius: 6;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px 3px 20px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align:center;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
font-family: Arial;
cursor: pointer;
}


.mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  display: none;
  width: 140px;
  bottom: -92px;
  left: -1px;
}


.itemscabecera.active .mega-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="itemscabecera active">
    <span>1st menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>2nd menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>3rd menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>4th menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>5th menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
  
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: That's a logic answer, but when clicking outside the buttons the menu item disappears again...

Answer (score 1):

On `document.ready` add the class active to the first menu element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a=$('.itemscabecera')[0]
 $(a).addClass('active');
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var a=$('.itemscabecera')[0]
 $(a).addClass('active');
})
$(document).on('click', '.itemscabecera', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('.itemscabecera').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});

$('.itemscabecera').on('click', function() {
  $('.itemscabecera').removeClass('active');
});

$(document).on('click', '.mega-menu', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation(); 
})
```

```css
.itemscabecera {width: 12%;
margin:0.15rem; 
-webkit-border-radius: 6;
-moz-border-radius: 6;
border-radius: 6px;
color: #ffffff;
padding: 15px 3px 20px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align:center;
float:left;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
font-family: Arial;
cursor: pointer;
}


.mega-menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  color: #000000;
  display: none;
  width: 140px;
  bottom: -92px;
  left: -1px;
}


.itemscabecera.active .mega-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>1st menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>2nd menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>3rd menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>4th menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
 
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="itemscabecera">
    <span>5th menu</span>
    <div class="mega-menu">
      <ul>
        <li>menuitem1</li>
        <li>menuitem2</li>
        <li>menuitem3</li>
  
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: This works except when clicking outside the buttons: the menu item disappears again.